# Vector of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, server, winsock

I am trying to make a Winsock server, that accepts many clients. In order to make that I was told to use a Vector of threads.So thats what I am tring to do but I got this error:

> Error 3   error C2064: the term does not evaluate to a function with 0 arguments 
>   C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 \ VC \ include \ functional 1152 1 Server

And my server code is  like this:

```
 using namespace std;
    int __cdecl NewClient(SOCKET ListenSocket, SOCKET ClientSocket,  char *recvbuf,  int recvbuflen, int iSendResult, int iResult)
    vector<thread> thred;

    int __cdecl main(void) {

            //things
             SOCKET ListenSocket=INVALID_SOCKET;
             SOCKET ClientSocket=INVALID_SOCKET;
             char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
             int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
             int iSendResult=0;
             int iResult;
            thred.push_back(thread(NewClient,ListenSocket, ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, iSendResult, iResult));
            thred[thred.size()-1].detach();
    }

    int __cdecl NewClient(SOCKET ListenSocket, SOCKET ClientSocket,  char *recvbuf,  int recvbuflen, int iSendResult, int iResult){
    //things
    }
```

I thinkthe error is where I try to make the pushback of the new thread. Is the pushback used  like this?Or what can I do?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cppreference.com says "std::thread is not CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable, although it is MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable."

Answer (score 2):

> Is the pushback used like this?Or what can I do?

cppreference.com says "std::thread is not CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable, although it is MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable."

Consider:

```
std::vector <std::thread*> thred;
```

and related adjustments.

Also, consider using a smart pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I based my code on the first example of this: [link](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/managing_threads_with_a_vector.html), so this is not possible? And with `std::vector <std::thread*> thred; ` what would the adjustments be?

Comment: That article says it should work, but my recent experience I did not figure out how.  Also, there are reasons to and I prefer a pointer.   So in my most recent effort, I used the "thread*" vector.  Other adjustments would be to use thred[i]->join(),  instead of thred[i].join() (i.e. dereferencing the pointer).  And with raw pointer, my dtor explicitly deleted each vector element using back(), pop_back(), and delete.  I think a thread has little else you need to invoke of it, so a pointer is really not a problem.  Good luck.

Comment: Just remembered, see  "void push_back( T&& value );"  (2) (since C++11).  I've not yet tried it.